Conditions for Epimorphisms in Commutative Diagrams: Can Monomorphisms Imply Epimorphisms in a General Category?
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, and let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three objects in $\mathcal{C}$ such that the following diagram commutes.

If $f$ and $g$ are monomorphisms and $h$ is an epimorphism, then we can easily conclude that $g$ is an epimorphism. If we further assume $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of sets, then we can conclude that $f$ is an epimorphism, i.e., $f$ is surjective.
My question is:

Can we conclude that $f$ is an epimorphism when $f$ and $g$ are monomorphisms and $h$ is an epimorphism in a general category $\mathcal{C}$?


Is there a counterexample in the category of rings? That is, when $f$ and $g$ are monomorphisms and $h$ is an epimorphism, we cannot conclude that $f$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings.


The assumption that f is a mono is not necessary for what you wrote.

A universal counterexample can be constructed as follows. Take four objects $X,Y,Z,T$. Take a unique morphism $f:X \to Y$ and a unique morphism $g: Y \to Z$. Take two morphisms $a,b : Y \rightrightarrows T$ which however compose to the same unique morphism $c:X \to T$, so that $af=bf$. Of course we also have the identities. In this finite category, all morphisms are monomorphisms, and except for $f$ every morphism is an epimorphism.
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
X & \longrightarrow & Y & \longrightarrow & Z \\
& \searrow & \downarrow \downarrow && \\
&& T &&
\end{array}$$
Actually the category of commutative rings is also a counterexample. If $A$ is a subalgebra of a localization $S^{-1} R$ (and let's assume that $S$ consists of regular elements so that $R$ is a subring of the localization), the composition $R \to A \to S^{-1} R$ is an epi, but there is no reason why $R \to A$ should be an epi. In fact, consider for example $R := \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$, $S:= R \setminus \{0\}$ (or just the powers of $Y$), and $A := \mathbb{Z}[X,Y,X/Y]=\mathbb{Z}[X,Y,U]/\langle UY-X\rangle$. Then $R \to A$ is not an epimorphism (since there are rings with zero divisors).
I am sure this can be adjusted to the category of all rings.
